# gtk+2.0 which widget to use for friends list?

Tags: c, gtk

I am just starting to look into gtk because I have to write a GUI application with it. It's an IM application and I need to show the user his/her friend list when he or she log in. The list should show a small picture on the left and name on the right ,like shown below:

```
Friends
-----------
Pic1  John
Pic2  Sara
...   ...
```

From what I know so far, I think the best suit is the Treeview, but it have annoying separators and headers so the list is like this:

```
Friends
------------
PIC  |  Name
------------
Pic1 |  John
------------
Pic2 |  Sara
```

Is there anyway to solve this? Or is there better way to achieve this?

Also I want to contain more information in the name part, like this:

```
Friends
----------
Pic1  John
Pic1  This is more about John
Pic1  Still more about John
Pic1  Sara
Pic1  This is more about Sara
Pic1  Still more about Sara
```

Notice that the three Pic1s and Pic2s still represent one picture above.

Also I am writing the application in C.

Suggestions?

Comment: Probably you will want to create your own composite widget for this and then pack a list of them into a scrolling container.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a multi-line string in the text cell renderer. For example, here's an example from an application I worked on: https://github.com/wmvanvliet/Chimara/blob/browser/player/browser.c.

Set a custom data function on your cell renderer:

```
gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func(column, renderer, (GtkTreeCellDataFunc)text_function, NULL, NULL);
```

This is an example of a custom data function that nicely formats the title, author, and year published of a work into the cell renderer's markup property:

```
static void
text_function(GtkTreeViewColumn *column, GtkCellRenderer *cell, GtkTreeModel *model, GtkTreeIter *iter, gpointer data)
{
    char *title, *author, *rendered_string;
    unsigned year;
    gtk_tree_model_get(model, iter,
        1, &title,
        2, &author,
        3, &year,
        -1);
    rendered_string = g_strdup_printf("<big><big><b><i>%s</i></b></big>\nby %s</big> (%d)", title, author, year);
    g_object_set(cell, "markup", rendered_string, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For TreeView, the column headers can be hidden with `gtk_tree_view_set_headers_visible(view,false)`.  This also seems to remove the column dividers, although I can't find any documentation on this behavior.